# Attempting to restore .img files to disk causes corruption

Tags: disk-utility

When I download .img files for writing to a CD or USB I've noticed a problem under OS X (including Mavericks). If Disk Utility recognizes the image and burns it, the resulting disk is corrupted. If Disk Utility doesn't recognize the image (e.g. a Raspberry Pi image) and I dd the image to a USB drive, the resulting disk is corrupted. Yet, I can take any of these images, download them to Ubuntu Linux and write them out perfectly.

I can't seem to get my head around why it doesn't work on OS X. I was hoping for some advice. In the course of writing this question I did notice some references on other Stack Exchange questions to hdiutil. Must I use that instead of the Disk Utility and dd?

Comment: To ward of any questions, the Mac and the Ubuntu box are on the same switch on the same LAN behind the same firewall so I think it's safe to rule out network issues.

Comment: How do you write the images on Ubuntu?

Comment: I think I found the answer to my own question! The process under Mac OS X is different than under Linux. 

 1. diskutil list - find the /dev/ of your device
 2. unmountDisk /dev/diskN - if it's attached
 3. sudo dd if=/path/to/downloaded.img of=/dev/rdiskN bs=1m

I was previously using the device id given in the Disk Utility App and not using bs=1m.